# How to fix gradlew permission denied in travis.yml?

Tags: android, gradle, build, travis-ci

When running my build on travisci, it seems to fail because of permission denial with gradlew file. How can I fix this? Here's what it says on Travis-ci.org:

```
   $ java -Xmx32m -version
     java version "1.7.0_76"
     Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_76-b13)
     Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.76-b04, mixed mode)
   $ javac -J-Xmx32m -version
     javac 1.7.0_76
     0.00s$ ./gradlew build connectedCheck
     /home/travis/build.sh: line 45: ./gradlew: Permission denied

     The command "./gradlew build connectedCheck" exited with 126.

     Done. Your build exited with 1.
```

Comment: This question is not a duplicate. I didn't see that one until afterwards.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I guess you can add something like this to your `travis.yml` file:

```
before_install:
 - chmod +x gradlew
```